# SSRS report subscription not working sometime

Tags: reporting-services, subscription

We have created 10 to 12 SSRS reports and created subscription for the reports. Sometimes the status of the subscription is showing mail sent but actually we have not received any email. What may be the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

Check the logs on the SMTP server (if your current logging level is not enough, consider logging more information ala http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Logging_the_SMTP_Service.html).

You might find the mailbox is full or there was some other mail problem, that is not reported by Reporting Services as it hands off sending to the SMTP server. You can find the SMTP server settings in Reporting Services Configuration Manager -> E-mail Settings.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It said Mail Sent but it was never received. I had no errors or warnings in logs, but the problem was that the attachment was too big.

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem with the first release of SSRS for SQL 2008.  The problem is generally corrected in the service pack.  The update makes the engine that sends the reports much more reliable and the jobs will show a failure if it doesn't get sent.  Previously, I would see that the job had run but wouldn't get any feedback on the server so it looked like it had run.  My users, however, gave me plenty of feedback that the report wasn't making it to them.

Also, If you are sending the email to several users and any of the users are no longer in the system you may see that the report failed but it doesn't give a good reason why.  The report wills send to the whole list at once, if any of the users on the email list the entire list will then not receive the report.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever received mail from that SSRS server? If not, the issue I've had is that Exchange hasn't had "relay for this host" enabled. You will find the error in the SSRS logs.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the receiving file size limit of the receivers end. Check your file size generated by the server and check the existing receivers limit of receiving attachments and increase it accordingly. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue in our system.  I discovered when sending to multiple recipients that the first one on the list never received the report.  I was able to solve the problem by **starting** every **To:** line with a semicolon.  Example:

```
To:  ;email1@myorg.org; email2@myorg.org
```